# Call a method in odoo11 POS after changing customer

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, odoo-11

There is a widget in the POS(point of sale) called `PaymentScreenWidget` and inside that there's a `customer_changed` method which is called when the customer is changed.

Suppose that I want to call a method after this method is called then how can I do this without interfering with this code?

Interfering with this code leaves a lot of trouble in many case so are there any ways to achieve this?

I want to append some text to it but since there are many module who try to change those code or override it I want to avoid doing it and try to call my method after that method has been called.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do some code instrumentation.
For example,

```
let old_customer_changed = customer_changed;
customer_changed = function(){
 // my awesome code
 old_customer_changed();
}
```

You'll have to implement similar thing in whatever modules you are using.